# How to fix 'Stack Overflow' error in Lua?

Tags: lua, stack-overflow

I'm trying to fix a Payday 2 BLT mod that crashes the game but I'm a beginner in both modding and Lua and the author doesn't update it for more than a year, I managed to track down the crashes to the line 13 of the script:

This is the error:

```
Application has crashed: C++ exception
mods/ShadowRaidLoud/lua/coremissionscriptelement.lua:13: stack overflow
```

From what I understand, `tostring(self._id)` might be causing the error, but I don't know what to do from here.

This is for a Payday 2 mod, removing the mod might stop the crashes but I'm looking to fix it myself. Tried contacting the author but without luck.

**coremissionscriptelement.lua:**

```lua
core:module("CoreMissionScriptElement")
core:import("CoreXml")
core:import("CoreCode")
core:import("CoreClass")

_G.ShadowRaidLoud = _G.ShadowRaidLoud or {}
ShadowRaidLoud = _G.ShadowRaidLoud
ShadowRaidLoud.Run_Script_Data = ShadowRaidLoud.Run_Script_Data or {}

local ShadowRaidLoud_OpenVault = MissionScriptElement.on_executed

function MissionScriptElement:on_executed(instigator, ...)
    local _id = "id_" .. tostring(self._id)   -- stack overflow crash here
    if ShadowRaidLoud and ShadowRaidLoud.Enable and not Network:is_client() then
        if (_id == "id_100961" or _id == "id_100962") and not ShadowRaidLoud.Run_Script_Data[_id] then
            local element = self:get_mission_element(100964)
            if element then             
                local msg = "[System] Vault will open in ".. ShadowRaidLoud.Time4Use.OpenVault .." seconds"
                ShadowRaidLoud:Announce(msg)
                local _tmp = ShadowRaidLoud:Run_Script("id_100964", self, 100964, element, instigator, ShadowRaidLoud.Time4Use.OpenVault)
                ShadowRaidLoud.Run_Script_Data["id_100961"] = _tmp
                ShadowRaidLoud.Run_Script_Data["id_100962"] = _tmp
            end
        end
    end
    ShadowRaidLoud_OpenVault(self, instigator, ...)
end
```

**EDIT:** I tried adding return to the last line of the function but it still caused crash with this crashlog:

```
Application has crashed: access violation

-------------------------------

Callstack:

         payday2_win32_release  (???)     ???                                                 


-------------------------------

Current thread: LoadingEnvironment

-------------------------------

System information:
    Application version : 1.92.790
    CPU : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz (2 cores); SSE; SSE2; SSE3; SSSE3; SSE4.1; SSE4.2
    DirectX : 12.0 
    GPU : NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070 / nvldumd.dll[26.21.14.3160]
    Language : english
    Memory :     16269MB 264KB
    OS : 6.1.7600 () 0x300-0x1 (64 bits)
    Physics : threaded
    Renderer : DX9 threaded
    Sound : Realtek Semiconductor Corp. (Speakers (Realtek High Definition Audio))
```

Comment: `MissionScriptElement:on_executed` invokes `ShadowRaidLoud_OpenVault` which equals to `MissionScriptElement.on_executed`.  Use recursion carefully (otherwise ouroboros will cause stack overflow in your program)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to test if that is the only issue, but since (as @Egor already mentioned) `hadowRaidLoud_OpenVault == MissionScriptElement.on_executed`, you should put a return statement before `ShadowRaidLoud_OpenVault(self, instigator, ...)` to turn it into a proper tail call:

```lua
function MissionScriptElement:on_executed(instigator, ...)
    --- SNIP ---
    return ShadowRaidLoud_OpenVault(self, instigator, ...)
end
```

At least that recursion should not cause the stack overflow again, as long as it keeps fulfilling the requirements for a tail call.

Comment: Oh ok I tried taking that last bit out but it still crashes so I'm gonna try returning it, since I noticed does the three dots passed as parameters actually exist in Lua? In other languages it's used as an alternative to write every single one.

Comment: @DarkCeptor44  Yes, `...`  captures any additional arguments given to a function, if used it must be in the argument list as well. If trail call does not suffice, you probably have circular events.

Comment: It did not work, it still crashes but this time the log is even less helpful, the log only says access violation.